# How to export GMail email between 2 persons to Microsoft Word?

Tags: windows, gmail, microsoft-word

I would like to export email between 2 persons (me and someone else) conversation we had since the last year. I need to have them in a Word document to be able to share it. It should be in a readable format.

Is there a way to do it without copy-pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gmail, there is no action that can "export" email. You can transfer the email to another email client that maybe can do this but with Gmail, it's not possible.

**EDIT:**

- ***Ivo:*** Connecting Gmail with Outlook can be found in your Gmail settings. One option would be if save the email (in Outlook) as html and open it in Word as the html formatting will be a lot more readable

Comment: He would have to get it into Outlook using pop or imap and then export it (if possible at all)

Comment: That's what I thought also since it's not possible with Gmail. Good comment Ivo!

Comment: Humm ok, any steps of how to do it? I might be able to find on Internet how to connect Gmail with pop3 but humm when in Outlook how can I export them in Word? :S

Comment: In Gmail's settings,  in POP/IMAP Transfer, you can transfer your email to another account or even enable POP and setup your gmail account on a third-party client like Outlook... You will find the setup instructions there.

Then, in Outlook (I have 2010), I right-click on my email, then COPY and I just paste it or I print it... I hope that's the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Connecting Gmail with Outlook can be found in your Gmail settings. One option would be if save the email (in Outlook) as html and open it in Word as the html formatting will be a lot more readable.

Go add this to your answer r0ca ;-)

Comment: However this won't really help with the problem. Question is about exporting conversations, so they look like conversations. Exporting mail to outlook or else will separate the mails, no?

Comment: Shouldn't the conversation appear as an email thread instead in Outlook?

Comment: I need them in the time I got them to be able to follow the logical date order when reading from the first page to the last. This must be "clean"... like reading a book from page 1 to page N. I will try the Outlook way tonight.

Comment: If you transfer your gmail account to Outlook, you will only see a delay of 1 minute or 2... Not that much. It will also come in a logical date order, no worry. Same thing for POP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this when searching for this same information:

[Export a Gmail message to Google Docs](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/12/17/export-a-gmail-message-to-google-docs/), by Brad Linder on December 17, 2008:

> I use a lot of Google services on a day to day basis, including Gmail,
>   Google Calendar, and Google Docs. So I'm always excited when Google
>   announces a new way to make these web apps play well together.
>   Yesterday the company announced a new feature in Gmail Labs that adds
>   a "create a document" link to your email menu.
>
> When you open an email and click the document link, the message will
>   be exported as a Google Document. From there you can edit it, share
>   it, or download it as a Word, PDF, or RTF file.
>
> In order to enable the feature, just click the Gmail Labs icon (it
>   looks like a beaker and hangs out next to the settings link in the top
>   right side of your Gmail homepage) and scroll down until you see the
>   Create a Document option. Click enable and Gmail will reload with the
>   feature enabled.